# Why am I getting this error upon trying to import a module from a different file on JS?

Tags: javascript, module

For some reason, every time I try to import a module from a different file it just keeps repeating those errors. I'm just using this simple test to import, and it's the same error as on the project I'm current working on.

This is on the Utils.js file:

```
export function iseven(x){
   return x%2==0
}
```

This is on the Main.js file:

```
import {iseven} from './Utils.js'
console.log(iseven(3))
```

If I just try to run the Main.js file, it tells me to either use the type: "module" on the package.json file or use the mjs extension, but even if I do so, it calls this error:

```
Info: Start process (17:05:12)
Error: 
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".tmp" for d:\Users\robso\Documents\Projeto\Archives\node_01cbcd545e361.tmp
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:71:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:105:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:31)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:17)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}

Info: End process (17:05:12)
```

All the files are on that Archives folder. I tried using `npm init` and just manually creating the package.json file, then adding the type:"module", but it calls this same error either way.

It mentions this file `d:\Users\robso\Documents\Projeto\Archives\node_01cbcd545e361.tmp` which doesn't exists at all, and clicking on it gives me the option to create the file. Running when this file exists calls the exact same error.

Since my project is not for web, I'm using this extension called Node.js Exec to run the code, so I thought it might be getting this error due to this. So I just created a html file and called the `Main.js` to check if it would work this time, and it showed a different error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./Main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I really just created the default white page and checked the console, that's the error this time:

```
Access to script at 'file:///D:/Users/robso/Documents/Projeto/Archives/Main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

I can't really say what's causing this, I tried to run some commands that were added on ES6 like `map` to check if I was using an outdated version, but it did run just fine, so I have no idea what the problem is.

--Update--

I did manage to import the function on the test using require, but it's still showing the same error when I use export import. I noticed that the code still sees the function inside the import, if my cursor is on the function name on the import line it shows it's parameters, that it returns a boolean and all that info.

I'm closing this question since the problem is kinda solved, but I'm still going to search more on what might be causing the import thing.

Comment: have you tried changing your file extensions from `.js` to `.jsm`?

Comment: you mean `.mjs`? It doesn't affect the outcome, if I just use mjs withou the package, it requests for it, and if I do with the package, it gives the same error I showed.

Comment: (yes, `mjs`. I wrote to quickly) "if I just use mjs without the package, it requests for it" isn't that what we want?

Comment: I mean, when it is using the mjs it just works as if it was the common js, it still doesn't work.

Comment: It makes the same requests as in "it tells me to either use the type: "module" on the package.json file or use the mjs extension"

Comment: "*Since my project is not for web, I'm using this extension called Node.js Exec to run the code*" - can you tell us more about this? That does indeed sound like the problem; the extension might be creating the temporary file and run it. Try starting `node` from a terminal instead.

Comment: miramac.vscode-exec-node That's the extension Id. I just tried to disable it and uninstall to check. I even created a new project excatly like this one to check if the extension was already set as a dependency or something, but when I checked the console on the HTML it showed the same error. How can I start node from a terminal like you said?

Comment: `node your-js-file.js` should do the trick if you have it installed?

Comment: That worked! So I should just run the files using the terminal instead of the extension, right?